# Brand wise building with Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, build, branding

I have a requirement to do webpack build based on the brand (use brand specific css to build). I want to pass the brand as an agrument while building. for example I have 2 brands brandA and brandB, I will have build commands as below.

- npm build --brandA
- npm build --brandB

Is there a solution for this kind of brand wise build in webpack? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, webpack is really good at this sort of thing once you get familiar with it. There are a few different ways you could approach it, but they all relate to how you set up your webpack config.

1. Write separate webpack config files for each 'brand.' This is the closest match to your example, because webpack has a CLI flag for specifying a config file to use, e.g. `webpack --config webpack.config.brand-a.js`
2. But most of your webpack config will probably be the same for each brand(especially if it's only the CSS that's changing). So rather than have duplicate code, you split out the parts that are the same in each brand's config file, maybe put each chunk in a /webpack directory at the root of your project as separate little JS modules. So you have a module for the loader config, and one for the plugin config, etc., and your config files each `require`/`import` those. Now your config files have a lot less boilerplate in them and are mostly just the parts that differ from build to build.
3. Once you start splitting up your webpack config there's a lot of ways to organize it. Although the normal webpack config format is to export a single config object, it also allows you to export an array of config objects from your config file -- in this case webpack will do a separate build for each config object in the exported array. So another way to implement this would be a single `webpack.config.js` file, where you write a little code to iterate through the brands and, for each one, push a config object into an array -- then export the whole array. The upside here would be you could run all the builds with a single command, as webpack takes care of creating separate processes for each build.
4. A word of warning -- build time can get pretty hefty. (Although I haven't been deep into it since v1.x and things have probably gotten better.) If you build a lot you might find that it's worth looking into webpack optimization to speed up the process.

Comment: How to configure the css/image file paths?